# Python Winapi Equivalent for Raspbian? (For automatic mouse movements)

Tags: raspbian, python, input-device, modules

I am trying to use Python to generate automatic mouse movements and clicks etc, however on windows I did this by importing winapi. Is there a way I can do this in raspbian?

Would love a response, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one!

You can install 'pyautogui' from pip3 :)

Syntax is really smooth, look it up if you have the same problem as me